# What is @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty exactly?

Tags: android, debugging

If you look at [LienarLayout's source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java), you'll notice that there is an annotations called `@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty.`  My questions is: what is `@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty` exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty` is an [annotation](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1_src/android/view/ViewDebug.ExportedProperty.html) used for debugging the Android framework. It's not part of the public API.

> This annotation can be used to mark fields and methods to be dumped by the view server. Only non-void methods with no arguments can be annotated by this annotation.

The ViewServer is not part of the public API. See [this](https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ab595104969c9906/290b4bfbef4f1d91) discussion about the view server where Android framework engineer Romain Guy says:

> The ViewServer is not a public API and should NEVER be used as such.

Comment: Actually this has changed since this answer you can use `ViewServer` as an stand alone utility class https://github.com/romainguy/ViewServer and `@ViewDebug.ExportedProperty` works great https://plus.google.com/+EvelioTarazonaCaceres/posts/fQ3G2QHaLx4